# FlashDevelop error while importing Box2D

Tags: import, box2d, flashdevelop

I'm new to flash development, so I'm watching a tutorial on how to use FlashDevelop. The video recommended I use Box2D and explained how to use it as a global classpath, which I have done.

I was messing around with the code using what the person in the video was showing, just trying to get an output. As I typed, FlashDevelop was adding in the import statements for me.

```
import Box2D.Collision.Shapes.b2CircleShape;
import Box2D.Common.Math.b2Vec2;
import Box2D.Dynamics.b2BodyDef;
import Box2D.Dynamics.b2FixtureDef;
import Box2D.Dynamics.b2World;
import Box2D.Dynamics.b2Body;
```

When I run the program though, it's returning this:

> col: 31 Error: Definition Box2D.Collision.Shapes:b2CircleShape could not be found.

It's returning a variation of that for each import.

I've checked and the files are indeed there. I'm really not certain what this could be; it's possible I just missed a step.

Any ideas?
(Sorry if I formatted this question incorrectly, I'm new to this site.)

Comment: i wonder if your problem was solved, if yes, could you please turn your question as resolved

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe cause  you are using an old version 
I think these are your choices :

**1) you have to do an update**

or

**2) use "b2CircleDef"**

See the code source in this link the change are commented
http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2010/01/27/box2dflash-2-1a-released-what-changed/

Hope that was helpful !

Good luck

Comment: I apologize. I forgot about this question. No, that did not solve the problem. I decided to try a different engine instead. Thanks for the reply!